# How to handle IF statement in AMP and .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, amp-html, accelerated-mobile-page

```html
@using App
@using Helpers
@model App.Model.Cache
@{
    ViewBag.Title = @Model.Title;
    Layout = null;
}
<!doctype html>
<html ⚡>
  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,minimum-scale=1">
      <style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-moz-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;-ms-animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both;animation:-amp-start 8s steps(1,end) 0s 1 normal both}@-webkit-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-moz-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-ms-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@-o-keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}@keyframes -amp-start{from{visibility:hidden}to{visibility:visible}}</style><noscript><style amp-boilerplate>body{-webkit-animation:none;-moz-animation:none;-ms-animation:none;animation:none}</style></noscript>
      <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
      <script async custom-element="amp-social-share" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-social-share-0.1.js"></script>
      <script async custom-element="amp-list" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-list-0.1.js"></script>
      <script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
      <script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
      <script async custom-element="amp-ad" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-ad-0.1.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato"/>


      @if (!Model.IsBookmark)
      {
          <link rel="canonical" href="@(Model.CanonicalUrl())"/>
      }
      else
      {
          <link rel="canonical" href="@Model.BookmarkURL"/>
      }
    <style amp-custom>
        body {font-family:Lato, Arial;}
        .related {
            background-color: #f5f5f5;
            display: block;
            clear: both;
            height: 64px;
            margin-bottom: 14px;
        }

            .related > span {
                font-size: 16px;
                font-weight: 400;
                vertical-align: middle;
                margin: 8px;
                line-height: 1.2em;
                height: 64px;
            }

            .related:hover {
                background-color: #ccc;
            }

        .related-recipes a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #444;
        }

        .related-image {
            width: 64px;
            height: 64px;
            float: left;
        }

        .related-text {
            display: inline;
            vertical-align: middle;
            color: #111;
            position: relative;
            top: 1.2em;
            left: .9em;
            text-overflow: clip;
            word-break: break-all;
            word-wrap: break-word;
        }
         amp-carousel amp-img > img {
             object-fit: contain;
         }

        amp-carousel figcaption {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            padding: 8px;
            background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); /* translucent black */
            color: #ddd;
            font-size: smaller;
            max-height: 30%;
        }

        amp-carousel .review {
            width: 25em;
            vertical-align: top;
            overflow: auto;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 16px;
            height: 80%; /* TODO easy way to ensure the bottom shadow is visible */
            white-space: normal; /* the enclosing div generated by amp-carousel sets it to nowrap */
        }

        amp-carousel .review:nth-child(even) {
            background: #FFFFFF
        }

        amp-carousel .review:nth-child(odd) {
            background: #94C2F9
        }

        amp-carousel .review h1 {
            font-size: larger;
            padding: 0;
        }

        amp-carousel .review p {
            padding: 0;
        }

        amp-carousel .review address:before {
            content: '-- ';
        }

        ul, ol {
            padding: 0 16px;
        }

        /* Unicode-based stars and half-star credit: amoniker, https://coderwall.com/p/iml9ka/star-ratings-in-css-utf8 */
        .star-icon {
            color: #ddd;
            font-size: 34px;
            position: relative;
        }

        .star-icon.full:before {
            color: #FDE16D;
            content: '\2605'; /* Full star in UTF8 */
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        }

        .star-icon.half:before {
            color: #FDE16D;
            content: '\2605'; /* Full star in UTF8 */
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            width: 50%;
            overflow: hidden;
            text-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
        }

        .logo {
            background-position: left 16px center;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-image: url(https://www.bigoven.com/assets/images/icons/bigoven-recipes.png);
            background-color: #fefefe;
            height: 38px;
            text-align: left;
            padding: 16px;
            padding-left: 72px;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .14), 0 3px 1px -2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 0 1px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
        }

        .logo > a {
            text-decoration: none;
        }

        .heading {
            text-align: center;
            padding-bottom: 8px;
        }

        .heading > #summary {
            font-weight: 500;
        }

        .heading > small {
            color: #656565;
        }

        .lower-wrapper {
            margin: 0em 1em 0em 1em;
        }
        .title-description {
            max-width: 310px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm having a problem with writing correct 'IF' statement in .NET and AMP. Statment look like this and it placed in a head section where suppose to be. AMP Validator throws me three errors:

1. Tag outside the body section
2. and two of 'link rel=cannonical' is 'body', but it can only be 'head'

Here is a code snippet of my if statement from my cshtml template:

```
    @if (!Model.IsBookmark)
    {
        <link rel="canonical" href="@(Model.CanonicalUrl())"/>
    }
    else
    {
        <link rel="canonical" href="@Model.BookmarkURL"/>
```

What is the correct way to handle if statement in AMP?

Comment: Can you post your whole view?

Comment: @M12Bennett Yes, please take a look at the code snippet.

Comment: what is this `⚡` symbol in your `<html>` tag?

Comment: @derloopkat It is AMP indicator. Here is the link explaining it in general [link](https://www.kayakonlinemarketing.com/blog/what-is-the-lightning-bolt-icon-in-google-all-about)